# Cooja - Expected declaraton specifiers in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors, contiki, cooja

I'm currently working on project based on Contiki-NG and Cooja and I'm trying to implement my C code on the Sky mote in the network simulator Cooja but I got the following error :

```
code.c:5:12: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '&' token
code.c:5:17: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before numeric constant
../../Makefile.include:347:recipe for target 'code.c' failed
make: *** [code.o] Error 1
Process returned error code 2
```

I've tried to find a solution on other posts but I didn't found any answers. Here is my c program below :

```
#include "contiki.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#define PERIOD CLOCK_SECOND*2
static struct etimer et;   // Define the timer
etimer_set(&et, PERIOD);   // Set the timer

/* Definition of the processes (actually a protothread) */
   PROCESS(blink_LED, "blink_LED");

/* Load this process at boot */
   AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&blink_LED);

/* The process */
   PROCESS_THREAD(blink_LED,ev,data)
   {
    /* Application starts */
       PROCESS_BEGIN();

    /* Main loop of the application */
       while(1){
                etimer_set(&et, PERIOD);
                PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT();
                printf("Event executed \n");

                if(etimer_expired(&et)){
                   printf("Timer RESET \n");    
                   etimer_reset(&et);
                }   

       }
    /* End of the process */
      PROCESS_END();
}
```

The error seems to be coming from this line :

```
etimer_set(&et, PERIOD);   // Set the timer
```

Thanks!

Comment: you're missing the `main` if it's a program, or another function if you're supposed to just create a function.  I think you should study C programming before attempting this.

Comment: I did some programs before at school on Instant-Contiki too and I had not to put the     main function and I didn't get any errors...

Comment: okay then there is something incorrect about your Makefile

Comment: Hi, I figured out days ago, please look the answer I gave to @Fabrice Derepas. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The instruction `etimer_set(&et, PERIOD);` calls the function `etimer_set`. The compiler complains because it expects a declaration. You can not directly invoque an instruction like the one you wrote. For instance here is the declaration of function `main` calling `etimer_set`:

```
int main () {
  etimer_set(&et, PERIOD);
  return 0;*
}
```

Comment: Ok, but even when I put the `main()` declaration I get some errors.

Comment: The two first line are the same but others appeared like :
`code.c: In function 'process_thread_blink_LED': 
 code.c:22:12: error: 'main' is normally a non-static function
 code.c: In function 'main':
 code.c:26:17: error: case label not within a switch statement
 cc1: all warnings treated as errors
`

Comment: Sorry for the edit, it's only possible to edit for 5 min and it's impossible for me to copy the errors from Cooja compiler so I have to write them.

Comment: I figured out how to do. Just need to put the `etimer_set(&et, PERIOD);` line before the `while(1)` loop and also include `#include "sys/etimer.h"`. Thanks!